# In my rails store, how do i send a confirmation email of an order, and one to myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I bought a Rails store (i am slowly learning), and when someone places an order, I know they get an email because of the following code in the `order_mailer.rb` file:

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com'

  def receipt(order)
    @order = order
    mail(to: order.user.email, subject: 'Your Order with Flagstuff.com')
  end
end
```

Is there an easy way to add myself as a CC to this email so I know when an order comes through?

From what I can gather, given my very limited knowledge of Rails, the `orders_controllers.rb` calls the `order_mailer.rb` when someone places an order.  If I could locate that code and insert another .rb file (`admin_email.rb`) that looks almost identical, but with my email address instead of `order.user.email`, I think that might work.

I am looking for an easy answer and a learning experience =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition the answer from David, you can also add yourself as bcc if you change the defaults line to this:

```
default from: 'xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com', 
        bcc: 'receiving_address@xxxxxxxx.com'
```

check out the docs for more examples: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Also, this railscast might be interesting: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mail(to: order.user.email, subject: 'Your Order with Flagstuff.com')
```

to this:

```
mail(to: order.user.email, bcc: "you@example.com", subject: 'Your Order with Flagstuff.com')
```

Comment: wow that is ridiculously easy. just an FYI would my solution would have worked, and it so, what would i be looking for in the controller file (just trying to understand a bit better, love your answer)

Comment: have a look at the links in jugglinghobo's answer